# Strange answer highlighting. What did I do?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts

I started typing an answer and all of a sudden the screen began jumping all around. I assume that I had probably entered a bunch of keyboard shortcuts (which I have enabled but don't know how to use). I think I had started typing my answer with the word "There ...." When everything finally stopped, [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43294956/3681880) looked like this in Ubuntu Firefox:

[image]

What does the grey highlighting mean? I couldn't get rid of it until I refreshed the window. What did I do?

Comment: You mean the slight border shadow? That's just the focused post for keyboard shortcuts. Try using `j` and `k` to switch focus. Or use `?` to show contextual help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, I meant the slight border shadow.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You've selected the answer with [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site):

[image]

Nothing to worry about.

If you want, you can disable these shortcuts in your [preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current). (the settings are site-specific)

Comment: Why is there a shortcut to select an answer? What useful thing could be accomplished with a selected answer?

Comment: @Suragch: See the screenshot I added. They can be used for quick access to votes / flag menus, for example.

Comment: @Suragch: how else would you know what you are voting on or adding a comment to when using the keyboard shortcuts? I can switch focus to a different post on the same page and vote on it and leave a comment without having to take my hands of the keyboard.

Comment: Got it. I understand now.

Comment: Nice to know what this is. I **don't** have keyboard shortcuts turned on, but I've had this happen three, four times the last year or so. My response has always been to copy my in-progress answer to the clipboard, refresh the page, and start over pasting in the in-progress work.